# Ajax Request Error using Jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a application in Fb as well as on website..

I am sending ajax request but in Fb it is working fine but in my own web it doesn't show nothing. On FireFug Console it shows Red Color.

Anybody have idea about this

Here is link of application

[FB Link](https://www.facebook.com/7ElevenCanada/app_378477418868706)

and

[Web Link](http://www.slurpee.ca/application/www.slurpee.ca/711storelocator/)

Here when we add pincode or city then click find.

It works for Fb only

Anybody tell me what was the exact problem

Comment: Perhaps you could include the code. Do you have the error shown in red? It's very hard to help just from the web links to pages of code. How do we even create the error? The Ajax request must come from a client-side event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://7elevenstores.ca/store_locator/getLatLng. Origin http://www.slurpee.ca is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What it means is, that you are trying to make a XMLHttpRequest (ajax request) to another origin (another domain). And that is not allowed. Ajax request may only go to the same origin the page is loaded from.

- Check out this [article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) on access policy
- And [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) about same origin policy for javascript

Answer (score 1):

You are making a Cross Origin Ajax request to 
https://7elevenstores.ca/store_locator/getLatLng

That is why the request is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://7elevenstores.ca/store_locator/getLatLng. Origin http://www.slurpee.ca is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I hope you got the reason.